# Domain Name in ASP.NET Impersonation

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET can we impersonate a domain rather than as user? I know the following is possible:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\userid" password="Password"/>

Can I perform something like following:
 <identity impersonate="true" userName="domain"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible.  In order to impersonate, you need a password, and domain groups don't exactly have a password.  It clearly goes against the architecture.

Just wondering, why would you need to impersonate a whole domain? There might be a better approach to your problem if you share it. :)

Comment: Well, say I have designate a user for impersonation. Some day leter the user has resigned from the organization. The System people delete the user's account. Now again I have to identify some other user account for impersonation. Had the architecture been supported domain, the things would taken care automatically.

Comment: It would be best to create a user designated for this task, that would not ever be deleted. In case the user does not exist (you can check using Win32 APIs), you should do some error validation. What if there are no using in the domain, or the user gets deleted?